# Como ultilizar a classe row no bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Tenho duas perguntas:

1ª - No bootstrap é obrigatório utilizar a classe "row" para envolver as colunas?

2ª - Posso ter mais que 12 colunas dentro da mesma classe "row"?

Exemplo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1º nao e obrigatorio,EX: se vc quiser preencher uma linha (row) basta md6 + md6 = md12 -  2º ate onde eu sei o maximo de colunas é 12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) as respostas para suas perguntas são as sequintes:

1. **No bootstrap é obrigatório utilizar a classe "row" para envolver as colunas?**

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative margin on .rows.

Ou seja, todas as colunas têm um "vão" entre elas que é definido por `padding` e é corrigido na `.row` com margens negativas. Então não é obrigatório mas não haverá a correção do `padding` das colunas.

2. **Posso ter mais que 12 colunas dentro da mesma classe "row"?**

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

Ou seja, sim, pode. As colunas excedentes cairão para a próxima linha.

---

**EDIT**

[Tutorial sobre o sistema de grids do Bootstrap 3](http://webdevacademy.com.br/tutoriais/ux/bootstrap-3-layouts-sistema-grids/) sugerido pelo @RenilsonAndrade.

Comment: Apenas completando a resposta, esse artigo: http://webdevacademy.com.br/tutoriais/ux/bootstrap-3-layouts-sistema-grids/ possui uma explicação de fácil entendimento de layouts e grids do Bootstrap.

Comment: Vou adicionar a resposta @RenilsonAndrade. Valeu!